Two Azure web apps using same Azure SQL Server, two databases
I have prod version of an Azure web app running.  I need to create a UAT version. I want to use the same Azure SQL Server but a different database.
When I go to create the new Web App:

I use the existing Subscription and Resource group.
I give it a new instance name Publish with code
Runtime stack is .NET 6 (LTS)
Region is the same as prod

When I go to Database tab I get a warning:

Creating a database requires a new App service plan.

so I can't seem to relate the new instance.
I've been testing with the 2nd instance in VS 2022 so there's no problem with it.  But I need a published version so that users can test it.
Can this be done, or have I missed something?

What do you have currently: Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Managed Instance or SQL Server on Azure VM?  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/azure-sql-iaas-vs-paas-what-is-overview?view=azuresql)

In hierarchical order (I believe)
Azure Subscription
Azure App Service Plan
Azure App Service
Azure SQL Server

SQL Database (prod)
SQL Database (uat)

